# Is it possible to include docker images into rpm or msi for installation (the we do SW/App installation)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to containerize my app and distribute that using RPM (on linux) / MSI (on windows). I do not want any registry dependencies.

Is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: Why not just push the image to a public registry (like dockerhub)?

Comment: In principle, yes, but you'd be better off directly packaging your application in an RPM/.deb/MSI and distributing that without Docker involved.

Comment: Any suggestion @DavidMaze how it can be done ? I have not just one component to containerize. I have multiple components those are with different dependencies. So do not want to disturb my setup as well as consumer's setup.

Answer (score 0):

This project seems to address exactly this problem: https://github.com/Scout24/docker-service-rpm
although it is not maintained anymore.

I would say for air-gapped environment it is quite a typical requirement honestly.